# if-condition is met but it doesn't apply (modulo)

Tags: javascript

I have very simple code looping through elements in an array and checking if `index % 2 == 0`. If so, it should change the color.

```
var e = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;
for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    console.log(i % 2);
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        e[i].style = "color: red";
}
```

And it’s just not working. Even if `console.log(i % 2)` prints `0` every second entry. If I change it to `if(true)` all of them become red. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ohh that was it, .children! thank you

Comment: This can also be done with CSS, by the way: [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `var e = document.getElementById("list").children;` instead of `var e = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;`.

`childNodes` includes text nodes. Not only don’t they have a `style` property, but also after every list item there’s likely a line break which the loop applies to, because every second child node is a line break.

For example

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

means:

```
<ul id="list">:
  #text "  \n"
  <li>:
    #text "A"
  #text "  \n"
  <li>:
    #text "B"
  #text "  \n"
  <li>:
    #text "C"
  #text "\n"
```

The `childNodes` are all the `<li>`s and all the `#text`s. The loop is likely only targeting the text nodes. `children` only includes all the `<li>`s.

Also, it’s better to use `e[i].style.color = "red";`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    console.log(i % 2);
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        e[i].style = "color: red";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="list">test</li>
<ul>
```

Try using `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score -1):

The code seems to be good, but can you try adding parentheses ?

```
if( (i % 2) == 0 )
```

Comment: I tried that and I tried with === but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try this then: if( (i%2) ) @J.Doe

Comment: same result weirdly :/

Comment: @J.Doe Very weird, can you try renaming the i var ? 
for(var  a = 0; a < e.length; a++ ) if( (a % 2) == 0 ) e[ a ].style = "color: red";

Comment: didn't change either and this is the only javascript code I have, I tried it in another browser with the same result